# Getting polymorphic association to pass validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `User`, `Profile`, `Buyer`, and `Seller` objects.

```
class User
  has_many :profiles
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true
  validates :user, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :profileable_type }
end

class Buyer
  has_one :profile, as: :profileable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, through: :profile # is this needed?
end

class Seller
  has_one :profile, as: :profileable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, through: :profile # is this needed?
end
```

I want to be able to stop creation of `Buyer` and `Seller` if a valid profile does not exist.

In the rails console, I am currently able to create a `Buyer` by creating a `Profile` without a `user:` value.  The following will create a `Buyer` without a `Profile` existing.

`> Buyer.create(profile: Profile.create)`

```
=> #<Buyer:0x00007fd44006cb80
 id: 1,
 user_id: nil,
 created_at: Mon, 06 May 2019 03:41:04 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 06 May 2019 03:41:04 UTC +00:00>
```

I would like to understand how to prevent this.  Do I need one of the `before_save` or such callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post, you want to add validation in polymorphic so just add the presence validation in the Model and it will work accordingly:

```
class Buyer
  has_one :profile, as: :profileable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, through: :profile # is this needed?

  validates :profileable, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

The second validation will rollback the transaction if user is not found.

Comment: Thanks.  For this to work, do I need to add `profileable_id` to the Buyer table migration?

Comment: I hope that you had already done that based on the associations posted in the question.